# How can avoid DatabaseSessionIsOver from outside calls

Tags: python, ponyorm

I have some definitions of models where I had overridden their `__repr__` methods. So for example, let's take into account the following entities:

```
def A(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(unicode)
    b = Optional("B")

    def __repr__(self):
       return self.name

def B(db.Entity):
    id = PrimaryKey(int, auto=True)
    name = Required(unicode)
    a = Required("A")

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{n} from a={aname}'.format(n=self.name, aname = self.a)
```

It is raising the `DatabaseSessionIsOver` exception whilst I was using `search(B, 'aaaa`)  method from [Flask-PonyWhoosh](https://github.com/piperod/Flask-PonyWhoosh) even if it are using `db_session` wrapped inside:

```
@orm.db_session
def search(model, *arg, **kw):
    return model._wh_.search(*arg, **kw)
```

The exception raises only when some entity override the  `__repr__` method in that way that I did in the example above.

However, I'am using to avoid the problem the following sentences:

```
with db_session:
    print(search(A, 'karl'))
```

So, shortly, the question is, is there any way to avoid the using of `with ...`, maybe modifying  the `__repr__` method or maybe modifying the methods from the package?.

Thanks,

**PD**: I've been reading [prefetch method](http://doc.ponyorm.com/queries.html#Query.prefetch) but it seems to be not appropriate. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

The exception `DatabaseSessionIsOver` happens because in your `repr` method you're trying to access the relationship attribute, which wasn't loaded from the database (`self.a` which tries to return the `name` attribute of the `A` entity).

One way to avoid this exception is to load all the necessary objects before you leave the `db_session`. In this case, those objects will sit in the Identity Map and no request to the database will be required.

Another way is to wrap all your code with a bigger scope `db_session`, so when you access the attribute which was not loaded from the database, Pony can do this within the `db_session`.

Pony requires using the `@db_session` because it sets the boundaries for the database conversation and allows freeing the resources:

1. Clear the Identity Map cache
2. Return the database connection to the connection pool

If we don't clear the cache, then all objects which were loaded from the database will sit in the memory until you clear the cache manually or your program ends.

Let's say we introduce the mode when the `db_session` never ends and you need to clear the cache manually. Do you think it would solve your problem and you would use it?